# Kendo TreeList with checkboxes on ASPNET Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-ui, treelist

I'm using Kendo (and I've almost never used it before) in an ASPNET Mvc application and I need to create a TreeList with checkboxes: checking a father should check all children and unchecking a child should uncheck the father (and the grandfather, and so on). 
The tree in itself works well: I've added a column with custom template and I'm using (successfully) the onClick event to get the value of the checkbox, but I can't figure out how to "bind" that value to the node of the tree (to reach every child and check it).

Here the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeList<TreeElem>()
  .Name("treelist")
  .Columns(col =>{                                                                
     col.Add().Field(f => f.NodeDescription).Title("TREE LIST");
     col.Add().Template("<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: checked' onClick='onCheck(event)'/>").Width(55);
   })
   .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "TreeController"))
   .Model(m => {                                                                                                
             m.Id(f => f.NodeId); 
             m.ParentId(f => f.ParentId);
             m.Field(f => f.NodeDescription);
       })
    )
)
```

In the javascript:

```
function onCheck(e) {
  console.log(e.target.checked); //print true/false according to the checkbox
  console.log($("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource.data()); //print the complete node list 
  //Other stuffs
}
```

I would like to get the right node from data() (or view()) according to the checkbox selected. Every node has references to his children and father, so the recursive function should be easy after that.
I've looked for and tried a lot of solutions but with almost no result, any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Is Kendo jQuery an option for you? Here is what you need implemented: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes

Comment: Also I found here for AspnetMVC https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/checkboxes so you have already a solution here with demo and everything. Have you tried this solution?

Comment: I'm actually trying with your first link, the problem is that TreeView is used instead of TreeList. TreeView doesn't allow to specify the type of the node (TreeElem in my case) and (i think) accepts only Json, so i have to parse everything (and i would like to avoid it, unless i have no choice)

Comment: Sorry I read it wrong. For List there is also an Events binding check the onEdit but in documentation it states that the selection is also possible: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treelist/events here for the select which is disabled by default https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/TreeListBuilder#methods-Selectable(System.Boolean)

Comment: I have been asked specifically for checkboxes, I don't think that onEdit event is triggered (but i'm going to try asap).
Selection will not solve the problem, i think, because it will allow the user to select just one element OR multiple element choosen. This means that he could select 2 fathers, while i need to limit that to one father and every child (my bad, i should have specified it in the question)